# Sharepoint Online: MSFT Management Activity API, incomplete details against SitePermissionsModified event

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, office365, sitecollection, azure-management-api

I'm using the Management Activity API to get events for External Sharing toggle for my O365 tenant collaboration/sharepoint site.

The documentation here [ManagementActivityAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt607130.aspx#spbase) lists down **SitePermissionsModified** as a potential match for that case.

When I change the settings (say NO EXTERNAL sharing) then I get the following event

```
{u'Workload': u'SharePoint', u'RecordType': 4, u'ObjectId': u'https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/myrc1', u'OrganizationId': u'xxxxxxxx-cce4-48ce-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx', u'UserId': u'abc.pqr@xyz.com', u'CreationTime': u'2016-01-20T07:45:52', u'ItemType': u'Web', u'Site': u'e000000-139e-45df-a5a7-0000000000', u'UserType': 0, u'EventSource': u'SharePoint', u'UserAgent': u'Mozilla/5.0 (blabla; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 blabla/43.0', u'UserKey': u'i:0h.f|membership|00034343shsdhs@live.com', u'Operation': u'SitePermissionsModified', u'Id': u'e000000-a830-469e-ca2f-08d3216db000', u'ClientIP': u'xxx.xx.xxx.xx'}
```

Now this event doesn't say what change has occurred? It just says SitePermissionsModified, is there a way to know what exactly happened?

Answer (score 1):

The SharePoint team is actively working on updating the sharing related audit events to include more details about the change that occurred.  I haven't gotten an ETA from them.  Will provide an update as I learn more.